# What is the derivative of $\sin^{-1}(\frac{x+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{2}})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

If we substitute $x=\sin \theta$ then we get the derivative to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ shown in the picture below

[image]

But instead of assuming $x=\sin \theta$ if we assume $x=\cos \theta$ we get the answer to be $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. Why the answers are different in this case? Where is the mistake here?

Comment: I am getting $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ only, can you show your workings.

Comment: @SwagBeastSKJJ He posted an image. Is it not acceptable?

Comment: In general, $\sin^{-1}\left(\sin f(x)\right) \neq f(x)$. See [this plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+arcsin%28sin%28theta%2Bpi%2F4%29%29%2C+theta%2Bpi%2F4)

Answer (score 2):

Actually,
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-x}{|\sqrt{1-x^2}-x|}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

See [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28arcsin%28%28x%2Bsqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%29%27).

So, the derivative is equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ if $\sqrt{1-x^2}-x>0$ that is if $-1<x<\frac1{\sqrt2}$ and $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ if $\frac1{\sqrt2}<x<1$.

Note also that when you substitute $x=\cos\theta$, you may get $\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta$ for the expression if you accept that $\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}=-\sin\theta.$

Comment: Yeah If substitute $x=\cos\theta$, I get  $\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta$ then I get both -ve and +ve answers but considering $x=\sin\theta$ I find no way to get both answers. Why I'm getting derivative for a certain interval, not the whole domain in this case?  Because I didn't assume or consider anything which limits it to a certain interval.  Doing the differentiation assuming $x=/sin /theta$ gives a derivative which is valid when $\sqrt{1-x^2}-x>0$. But why I'm not getting the derivative for the other values of x.

Comment: When you subs $x=\sin\theta$, then $-\frac\pi 2<x<\frac\pi 2$ and half of this interval is not acceptable.